# Can I access an array created in one awk script in a subsequent awk script?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a shell script where there are 2 awk strings.

```
first_awk='
BEGIN {
}
{
# create some array here..
}
END{
}
'



second_awk='
BEGIN {
}
{

## Access the array created in first awk section.
}
END{
}
'
```

Is it possible to do something like above? Accessing an array created in first awk section in the later awk section?

Or, can I have an array declared in enclosing shell script and access that in both the awk strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign bits of awk code to shell variables that you then combine to create a single program fed to a single invocation of awk then you can access
arrays created in one from the other.  However it looks more like you are creating separate awk programs to be fed to separate invocation of awk.  In that case code passed to one awk won't know about code passed to the other (including array declarations).

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me that if you try

```
awk -f first_awk -f second_awk ...
```

awk file will "merge" according to call order. You can use variable/array define in `first_awk` from `second_awk`.

However, if you try

```
awk -f first_awk ...
/bin/ls
awk -f second_awk ...
```

`second_awk` have no way of knowing variable/array used during first_awk's call.

Each awk call create a new process which is discarded at the end of the run.